# Apprtcdemo ios app: Assertion failure in -[RTCICEServer initWithURI:username:password:]

Tags: ios, webrtc

I used this project i.e. https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios. It compiles fine.But after entering room no: Iam getting this following error.How to rectify this error?

```
2014-03-10 15:58:01.421 AppRTCDemo[4159:907] *** Assertion failure in -[RTCICEServer initWithURI:username:password:], ../../../talk/app/webrtc/objc/RTCICEServer.mm:40
2014-03-10 15:58:01.438 AppRTCDemo[4159:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'nil arguments not allowed'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31dfe2a3 0x39a5897f 0x31dfe15d 0x326d3ab7 0x17e07b 0x1b717 0x327396fd 0x326791f9 0x32679115 0x31adb45f 0x31adab43 0x31b02fcb 0x31d4474d 0x31b0342b 0x31a6703d 0x31dd3683 0x31dd2ee9 0x31dd1cb7 0x31d44ebd 0x31d44d49 0x358c12eb 0x33c5a301 0x12a61 0x39e8fb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Help is highly appreciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason, URI is nil when trying to create RTCICEServer instance.
To fix this navigate to APPRTCAppClient.m file
look for

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection method
```

just before the end of the function you should find a enumerator looping through servers
inside that loop update the following line

```
    NSString *url = [server objectForKey:@"url"];
```

to this

```
    NSString *url = [server objectForKey:@"urls"];
```

This should work!

Comment: Yes. Atlast I found the solution after struggling for a long time. It worked.